# Error consulta sql La consulta ha devuelto un valor que no es correcto sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

intento asignarle un valor a una variable, pero me genera un pequeño inconveniente

> La consulta ha devuelto mas de un valor lo que no es correcto

mi consulta es la siguiente, que puedo hacer para obtener todos los datos de esta consulta en la variable

```
declare @Temp Date 
set @Temp = (select eq.Fecha_adquisicion from Equipo eq
inner join Empleados e on e.ID_Empleado = ID_Empleado )
```

Comment: Pues no se puede....una variable puede tener un único valor asignado, a menos que sea una variable tipo tabla

Comment: Intenta declarar un cursor y guardando el resultado en una variable %rowtype

Comment: algo asi @Lamak `declare table @Temp`

Comment: Depende de lo que quieres hacer....lo mejor sería que pusieras para qué lo necesitas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utiliza un cursor.

Con este básicamente *recorres* el resultado del query, que puede ser de ninguna, una o muchas filas. Para cada fila, vas recogiendo el resultado en variables dentro de un ciclo y puedes hacer con ellas el proceso que sea necesario.

Por ejemplo, para recoger la fecha adquisición de la consulta que incluyes en tu pregunta, puedes hacer algo como:

```
/* declaramos el cursor, que es similar a declarar una _variable_ pero para un select */
declare cFechaA cursor for
select eq.Fecha_adquisicion 
  from Equipo eq
       inner join Empleados e on e.ID_Empleado = ID_Empleado;

/* No utilizaré @Temp, esta es la variable donde recojo cada fecha de adquisición */
declare @FechaAdquisicion Date;

/* abrir el cursor y obtener los datos de la primera fila */
open cFechaA;
fetch next from cFechaA into @FechaAdquisicion;

/* en este ciclo recorremos todas las filas del cursor */
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
  print convert(date, @FechaAdquisicion, 121);
  --hacer algo más con cada @FechaAdquisicion
  fetch next from cFechaA into @FechaAdquisicion;
end;

/* finalmente lo cerramos y liberamos los recursos que utiliza */
close cFechaA;
deallocate cFechaA;
```

Comment: Hacer esto es una garantía de tener un sistema lento. SQL Server (y la mayoría de los RDBMS) están optimizados para trabajar con conjuntos y no con datos escalares. Además, las opciones por default para crear un cursor no son las óptimas.

Comment: Entiendo tu preocupación, pero por otro lado, las generalizaciones no vienen bien; en este caso particular no se tiene información que permita concluir que será lento. En temas de optimización, yo acostumbro no sacar conclusiones a priori, ni optimizar prematuramente. Quizás son solo unos cuantos datos, quizás es un proceso que corre una vez al año. El AP está buscando solución para procesar múltiples filas con una variable escalar y yo se la estoy dando. Creo que estas otras consideraciones están fuera del tema y no diría que el uso de cursores, en general, sea garantía de nada.

Comment: Por otro lado, estoy contigo en que el uso indiscriminado de ellos no suele ser la solución más óptima, y muchas veces se puede obtener los mismos resultados, en un menor tiempo, tratando los datos como un conjunto. Solo, evito generalizar, pues a veces, una diferencia de medio segundo en un proceso que toma medio segundo y que se ejecuta pocas veces, no hace mayor diferencia.

Comment: Por eso mismo le pedí que hiciera una pregunta que involucrara todo su problema y resultó que no necesitaba un cursor. Desgraciadamente, para alguien con un martillo, cualquier cosa se convierte en un clavo. El usar un cursor con el pretexto de que son unos cuantos datos puede ser el inicio de una epidemia de cursores que terminen por hacer un sistema inutilizable. No todos los cursores son malos, pero su uso correcto en general es limitado.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer esto de distintas formas y todo depende de lo que quieras hacer.

Para corregir el error, puedes asegurarte de regresar sólo un valor mediante la instrucción TOP. Recuerda que debes especificar un orden para que puedas tener confianza de que valor se asignará.

```
DECLARE @Temp Date;
SET @Temp = (SELECT TOP (1) eq.Fecha_adquisicion FROM Equipo eq
             INNER JOIN Empleados e ON e.ID_Empleado = ID_Empleado 
             ORDER BY Fecha_adquisicion DESC);
```

La otra opción que es una forma común pero tiene un comportamiento un poco distinto es usando el SELECT para asignar valores.

```
DECLARE @Temp Date;
SELECT TOP (1) 
       @Temp = eq.Fecha_adquisicion 
FROM Equipo eq
INNER JOIN Empleados e ON e.ID_Empleado = ID_Empleado 
ORDER BY Fecha_adquisicion DESC;
```

La principal diferencia es que si la consulta no regresa ningún valor, con la primera opción se asignará un NULL a la variable, y con la segunda no se cambiará el valor de la variable. Otra diferencia es que la segunda opción permite asignar valores a múltiples valores al mismo tiempo en vez de utilizar múltiples comandos.

Si lo que quieres es almacenar todos los valores, lo que necesitas en una variable tipo tabla que recibe los valores de forma distinta a una variable escalar, pero igual a una tabla común.

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE(
    Fecha_Adquisicion Date
);

INSERT INTO @Temp( Fecha_Adquisicion)
SELECT eq.Fecha_adquisicion 
FROM Equipo eq
INNER JOIN Empleados e ON e.ID_Empleado = ID_Empleado;
```

En esta opción eliminamos el ORDER BY porque no existe el orden dentro de una tabla.

Comment: necesito todos los registros que me puedan resultar de esa consulta

Comment: Entonces usa una variable tipo tabla. Ahí dejé el ejemplo de como hacerlo. No puedes asignar múltiples valores a una variable escalar. En T-SQL no existen los arreglos (arrays).

Comment: en caso de que necesito recorrer cada uno de los datos de esa variable como lo haria?

Comment: Lo mejor es no recorrer dato por dato sino usarlo como un conjunto. Te recomiendo que abras otra pregunta que presente el problema que necesitas resolver y va más allá de asignar valores a variables y consumirlos.